# React Native Fetch POST/PUT sends null value

Tags: android, react-native, fetch

been working on this one about a week already. So i'm using React Native's fetch method to access our API. Using the GET method works, means that i was able to get data in our API. The problem now is the POST and PUT methods, when using PUT to send data, the value passed is always a null value. I tried using console.log in chrome browser, the response is 200, so means its ok and it was able to talk to the API, the only this is that the value is sent is always a null value. Note also that manually updating the data using Postman works, only doesnt work when API is called from React Native. help will really help me continue my development since i'm really stuck with this one. Thanks a lot guys

[See this file to see some code snippets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RrnK.png)

Comment: Did you resolve this issue ??? If yes, please let me know I have the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had this issue before and what I found out about the problem is:

Our server does not prepare api for "utf-8", and android avd sent requests with "charset=utf-8". So it will cause one of the platform showing error because the request charset is not same.

The issue is here and they still not fix it: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8237

Comment: @EJoshuaS: If you would read this post, you would recognize, that it is indeed an attempt to answer, and no hint of a *different question* to be found. When reviewing, read beyond the first "*I also had this issue before*"

Comment: I also have the same issue can you elaborate on what exactly needs to fix this issue.

Comment: @srinivas the issue I had was fixed, so if you still have this kind of issue, it might cause by another bug in react native

Answer (score 1):

Check the Content-type in the headers of your POST and PUT requests. Set it to application/json if your API takes parameters in JSON format.

Comment: actually the headers are already there. Accept:application/json and Content-Type:application/json. You can take a look at the attached file for the code snippets. been really working on this one for a week already and its making my development stuck up. Anyway thanks for the response

Comment: have you tried printing 'data' passed to your put method?

Comment: yea i tried debugging the passed data by alerting it

Comment: and did it get successfully passed?

Comment: how about we continue discussion on chat.

Comment: first. is the 'data' param successfully displayed on alert?

Comment: yea it was displayed

Comment: can you try to change your console.log in put method to 'return res;'

Comment: yea its already returning the res. and it returns ok. u can look at the file attachment to see the code

Comment: do u use whatsapp? can we talk there?

Comment: try to remove JSON.stringify then see what your API backend is receiving.

Comment: removing the JSON.stringify will cause an error. Also the fetch code snippet i used is from the facebook docs